# Kubernetes on AWS - managing virtual IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I've just set-up a 3-node Kubernetes cluster on AWS using Kelsey's [guide](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way). I notice that K8 assigns a unique virtual IP address to each pod and service. In the guide, a AWS route table is used to map the virtual IPs to actual IPs. While this works, it seems quite primitive and is not scalable when nodes are added/removed to the Kubernetes cluster.

What's the standard way to handle these virtual IPs when hosting Kubernetes on AWS at scale?

Comment: I think Kelsey's guide is very useful to understand how Kubernetes actually works but there are better choices to deploy Kubernetes on AWS, like CoreOS `kube-aws` or `kops`. https://github.com/coreos/kube-aws   https://github.com/kubernetes/kops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS route tables have a limit of 50 entries each, so that's not a very scalable solution. The most common approach is to use an overlay network. Two popular ones are

- [CoreOS Flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel)
- [Weaveworks Weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave)

The Flannel README in particular gives a good overview of how it works.